# Routing issue in angular while define routing with parameter

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

i have two routes defined like this

```
children: [
                            {
                                path: 'Templates', component: TemplatesComponent
                            },
                            {
                                path: 'AddEditTemplate/:id', component: AddTemplatesComponent
                            }]
```

I have "cancel" button on AddTemplatesComponent view

```
<a class="btn btn-default no-margin" [routerLink]="['../Templates']">Cancel</a>
```

But clicking on cancel button it not navigate to "Templates" component and the url changed from "/AddEditTemplate/5" to "/AddEditTemplate/Templates". But url should change to "/Templates".

What am i doing wrong? please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you have to go up 2 routes in the path. For example, let's suppose you're at `root/AddEditTemplate/2`. If you go up 1 route in the path, you'll be at `root/AddEditTemplate`. So, to be in `root` again to get to `root/Templates`, you should go up 2 routes in the path:

```html
<a class="btn btn-default no-margin" [routerLink]="['../../Templates']">Cancel</a>
```

Checkout this [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma613865196433166) => focus just in the files inside `module-1` folder.

**[UPDATE]:** If you want to navigate programmatically, you can use the `navigate` method of the `Router` with 2 arguments: the same route as above and a config options containing the `relativeTo` attribute specifying the current route as a starting point to calculate the relative paths. According to the [docs](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate): *If no starting route is provided, the navigation is absolute*.

```js
constructor(
  private _router: Router,
  private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
) {}

...

_navigate() {
  this._router.navigate(['../../Templates'], {
    relativeTo: this._activatedRoute
  });
}
```

Comment: it worked for button. Thanks.
But i also i want to navigate using router through ts file. i am using this code " this._router.navigate(['../../Templates']);". but it gives me error "Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'Templates'". Any solution? thanks.

Comment: My advice is: don't use relative routes if your're not working with a library. It kills the reusability of your components if you don't do it in the right way.

Comment: I'm not near a computer right now, but I remember the navigate method having an object as a second parameter where you could specify, among other things, that the navigation was relative to some specific route. Try looking at the docs. I'll take a look at it later, but it's strange because I think the default is to consider the navigation relative to the current route.